# Is there a R function for using ifelse with 2 conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, case, subset

This is the sample of my data

```
a<-c(NA,NA,NA,65,75,85)
b<-c(12,15,22,65,20,30)
c<-(12,15,22,65,75,85)
data<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I am trying to create a new variable d, such that if a=NA then b, if a=b then a and finally, if a>b then a.

My final data `d<-c(12,15,22,65,75,85)`

Thankyou

Comment: You can nest `ifelse` statements - or have a look at `dplyr::case_when` which is a generalised version.

Comment: @AndrewGustar we cannot compare a value with an `NA` as that will always return `NA` (as mentioned in the `R` help)

Comment: @DebarthaPaul That's what `is.na()` is for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is done using `dplyr::case_when` Note that in this code, if `a < b` will result an `NA` value.

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(d = case_when(
    is.na(a) ~ b,
    a == b ~ a,
    a > b ~ a
  ))
#>    a  b  c  d
#> 1 NA 12 12 12
#> 2 NA 15 15 15
#> 3 NA 22 22 22
#> 4 65 65 65 65
#> 5 75 20 75 75
#> 6 85 30 85 85
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>